# Parse Queries in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

Today was my first day with Parse, and I have a problem which I can't solve:

I made this void:

```
public void GetUserOfParse()
{
    parseState = parseInfoState.BEFORE_QUERY;
    int i = 0;
    var userQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("UserInfo").WhereEqualTo("userID", PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserId());     
    userQuery.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Debug.Log("in continuation"); 
    }
}
```

Now, if I launch the project in Unity Editor, it works great -  PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserId() is '0' in Unity Editor, so FirstAsync returnes me ParseObject with userID==0. 
But when I try to launch it on android device, there's no response from FirstAsync, it does not enter the ContinueWith, I don't get "in continuation" debug.

Is there something more I need to do to make  queries work outside the editor?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to troubleshoot problems without system feedback; therefore, I recommend checking out this [link](https://parse.com/docs/unity/guide#handling-errors) to find out what is needed to get the system to display error codes.

In the link above, this code example is provided a few paragraphs down from the header and this looks like a great place to start with debugging the issue.  If this code can be worked into your solution you should begin to see where to go from here.

```
try
{
    user.SignUpAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
        if (t.IsFaulted) {
            // Errors from Parse Cloud and network interactions
            using (IEnumerator<System.Exception> enumerator = t.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator()) {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                    ParseException error = (ParseException) enumerator.Current;
                    // error.Message will contain an error message
                    // error.Code will return "OtherCause"
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
catch (InvalidOperationException e)
{
    // Error from the SDK logic checks
    // e.Message will contain the specific error
    // ex: "Cannot sign up user with an empty name."
}
```

After the system begins to report error codes, take a look at this [link](https://parse.com/docs/unity/guide#errors) to find out what those error codes mean to determine the next step in the troubleshooting process.  I hope this helps.

Comment: On SignUpAsync without user and password set, the error is reported correctly, but I guess it's because it's checked before sending data to Parse database. I also tried simple `var obj = new ParseObject("obj1");
      obj["f1"] = "f1_Content";
      obj.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t => { Debug.Log("saved"); });`, and again, in Unity Editor and compiled to exe file it works fine, on android it does not save my object to server, and does not give me "saved" Debug.

Comment: Problem solved, I accidentally copied UnityEngine.dll to my project with Parse.Unity.dll